# Ajax POST sometimes fails to invoke ASP.NET MVC controller action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 based application and seeing intermittent problems when trying to perform an Ajax POST (via jQuery) to one of the controller actions. Sometimes, the controller action is invoked just fine and the code performs as expected, but other times, the  controller action is never invoked and the browser basically hangs there until the request eventually times out.

It's frustrating because we can't consistently reproduce the problem. On the other hand, it happens frequently enough that we can usually get it to happen without too much effort. I can see in Firebug's "Net" tab that browser definitely makes POST request, and I know that it's hitting the correct URL. One thing I haven't yet done, but which I've seen suggested elsewhere, is to set up Fiddler in the middle to see how far the request gets. But assuming it makes it as far as the web server (IIS), what should be my next step in debugging this? I don't have a strong Windows/.NET/IIS background and as a result I'm not sure where to start looking.

**Update:**

Here's the jQuery code that performs the POST:

```
var self = this;
var jsonData = foo.toJSONString();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/MyController/AddFoo',
    data: { foo: jsonData },
    success: function (data) {
        self.showSuccessfulSubmissionDialog();
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
       self.showUnsuccessfulSubmissionDialog(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

and here's the C# code for the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public JsonNetResult AddFoo(string foo)
{
    var fooObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(foo, SerializerSettings);
    try
    {
        // Do something with fooObject
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var formattedString = ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", " ");
        return BuildErrorResult("An error occured writing data to the server: " +
            formattedString);
     }
     return BuildSuccessResult();
}
```

A few minor details (especially variable names) have been changed, but the gist of it is as shown here. Also as noted previously, on the occasions when this "breaks" Firebug claims that the POST was executed but I never land at my breakpoint at the beginning of the controller action; so somewhere along the way, the ball gets dropped. Except those times when it doesn't, and the controller action executes with no trouble.

Comment: Can you show the code for the POST and the server action?

Comment: If you are using IIS7, you might consider using Failed Request Tracing to see what you can find. http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr

Comment: @rae1n, I've added the code for the client-side POST and the server-side controller action.

Comment: @HackedByChinese, thanks very much for the lead on Failed Request Tracing. I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use "complete" instead of "success", success gets fired when the server returns 200 status code. Complete gets fired every time the request is complete

```
$.ajax({
...
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
       self.showUnsuccessfulSubmissionDialog(xhr.responseText);
    }
...
});
```